# Terratest - How to check for terraform output

Tags: terratest

Is it possible to have `terratest` run an assertion for a value to exist, instead of the standard assertion that the value = expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [func NotEmpty](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert#NotEmpty), remember that Terratest is just a wrapper of Golang.